# Javascript : Preload loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, onload, preloading

I'm having trouble when displaying my loader in Javascript. Indeed, I have a lot of **heavy videos** in my assets folders, and when I load my page in Javascript, my image loader is showing only after a few seconds, whereas i would like it to be loaded first.

Is there a way to preload it, before all my video assets ?

Thanks a lot by advance !

Answer (score 0):

In a script that gets run before any of the videos start downloading, etc.:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://yoursite.com/preload-this-image.gif';
```

This should ensure that the image displays as soon as the DOM renderer reaches it.

If there are any heavy assets before it in the DOM holding back that process, you can move them ahead and move them back after document load with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a loader gif before the whole page renders:

CSS:

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('/img/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually convert the image into a base-64-encoded string, and include it in your CSS or HTML.  This guarantees that it'll be loaded before anything else.

Here's an image converter: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

And you can use it as an inline image, or CSS background image:

Inline HTML:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
```

or CSS:

```
background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my JS, Scott.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would hard code image in the source of the page as base-64-encoded string, or replaced with an inline svg.
Also you could use rel="preload" and see if this works out for you:

```
 <link rel="preload" href="bg-image.png" as="image" media="(max-width: 800px)">
```

see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content